# How to fill pyspark column recursively

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe, `df`, which look like this:

| row_num | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 8 |
| 2 | 45 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

Now I want to create column C which equals the value from A when row_num = 1 and C(row_num-1) + B otherwise. Hence, the dataframe should look like this:

| row_num | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 8 | 10 |
| 2 | 45 | 4 | 14 (10+4) |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 23 (14 + 9) |

I tried this command: `df.withColumn("C", F.when(F.col("row_num") == 1, df.first().A).otherwise(F.lag("C").over(window_spec) + F.col("B")))`, where `window_spec = Window.orderBy("row_num")`. However, this only fills the first row in column C and `null` in the other rows. Anyone knows how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark does a distributed processing so you cannot reference a column that you are processing. In your case, instead of `row2.C = row1.C + B`, you should consider it as

```
row1.C = row1.A
row2.C = row1.A + row2.B
row3.C = row1.A + row2.B + row3.B
...
rowN.C = row1.A + (row2.B + row3.B + ... + rowN.B)
```

`row2.B + row3.B + ... + rowN.B` can be derived with SUM window function like this.

```
w = Window.orderBy('row_num').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

# do row1.B + row2.B + ... + rowN.B - row1.B to achieve row2.B + ... + rowN.B
F.sum('B').over(w) - F.first('B').over(w)
```

Combine this in when/otherwise condition.

```
w = Window.orderBy('row_num').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

df = (df.withColumn('C', (F.when(F.col('row_num') == 1, F.col('A'))
                          .otherwise(F.first('A').over(w) + F.sum('B').over(w) - F.first('B').over(w)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test this logic:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example_app").getOrCreate()

data = [(1, 10, 8), (2, 45, 4), (3, 6, 9)]
columns = ["row_num", "A", "B"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

window_spec = Window.orderBy("row_num").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)


df = df.withColumn(
    "aux",
    F.when(F.col("row_num") == 1, F.col("A")).otherwise(F.col("B"))
).withColumn("C", F.sum("aux").over(window_spec))

df = df.drop("aux")  # Drop auxiliary column if you don't want it
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

actually for me to make this working, I will advice you to use json/dict type to process your data as you want, you may didn't hear about it, but there is a new package in pip allows you to process in json data as you want and insert data and make all what you want.

the code will be something like this :

```py
from JsonDF.utils.Json.Json import Json

json = Json('data', {}).objectiy()

json.insert('A', [10, 45, 6])
json.insert('B', [8, 4, 9])

# hence you want the value of c to be the c[row_num - 1]+b[row_num]
# you can make it like that

json.insert('C', [])

for i in range(len(json.B)):
    if i == 0:
        json.C.append(json.A[i])
    else:
        json.C.append(json.C[i-1] + json.B[i])

print(json)
```

the output will be like that :

```
{'A': [10, 45, 6], 'B': [8, 4, 9], 'C': [10, 14, 23]}
```

download JsonDF from pip with `pip install JsonDF` or from [GitHub](https://github.com/OsamaElsherif/JsonDF)
hope it hekps